# numpy replace a value by a negative int

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am doing a game of tic tac toe as an exercise. I am trying to replace X with 3, O with -3 and - with 0.

```
import numpy as np

playfield = np.array([
   ['X', 'O', 'X'],
   ['-', 'X', 'O'],
   ['-', '-', 'X']
])
codes = {'X': 3, 'O': -3, '-': 0}

for idx, x in np.ndenumerate(playfield):

    playfield[idx] = codes[x]
```

However, every time the program tries to replace an O by -3, my array is like this

```
[['3' '-' 'X']
 ['-' 'X' 'O']
 ['-' '-' 'X']]
```

It happens even if I try to replace it by -9. Also, when I try to replace '_' by -3, it appears as '-' in the array

If I make playfield as a normal list, replace everything and make it back as a np.array, everything works. Why is it happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`playfield` is an array of characters, so any negative number becomes `'-'`. If you change `'O'` to a positive integer, it should work fine.

For example if you use:

```
codes = {'X': 3, 'O': 2, '-': 0}
```

Then the result is:

```
array([['3', '2', '3'],
       ['0', '3', '2'],
       ['0', '0', '3']], dtype='<U1')
```

However, iteration over an entire array is perhaps the worst way to do substitution in numpy.

Something like this would be more efficient:

```
for k in codes.keys():
    playfield[playfield == k] = codes[k]
```

If you want your final array to be an array of `int`s, I would go about the conversions like so:

```
import numpy as np

playfield = np.array([
   ['X', 'O', 'X'],
   ['-', 'X', 'O'],
   ['-', '-', 'X']
])
codes = {'X': 6, 'O': 3, '-': 0}

for k in codes:
    playfield[playfield == k] = codes[k]

playfield = playfield.astype(int) - 3
```

This way you can still start with an original array of characters, and you'll only have to do a type conversion once.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer why it is happening. Your playfield is an array of U1 (whatever it is), and so -3 gets cast to the `<U1` type If you define

```
playfield = np.array([
   ['X', 'O', 'X'],
   ['-', 'X', 'O'],
   ['-', '-', 'X']
], dtype=object)
```

and also

```
codes = {"X": "3", "O": "-3", "-": "0"}
```

Everything works (you will have to cast the array back to ints at the end of your substitution. ) A little horrible, but not too surprising, since `numpy` is  (as the name suggests) designed for arrays of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you would need:

```
playfield = playfield.astype('U2')
for k, v in codes.items():  playfield[playfield==k] = str(v)
playfield = playfield.astype(np.int)
```

output:

```
[[ 3 -3  3]
 [ 0  3 -3]
 [ 0  0  3]]
```

**Explanation**: Your `playfield` array is an array of a single character. To include a two character `"-3"`, first convert `playfield` to a two character array `'U2'`(please be aware that if you choose to use larger than single digit numbers, you need to expand your string array to maximum characters in the largest number `'Un'`) and then replace with string version of numbers and finally convert them to numbers on last line.

Answer (score 1):

I would just create a new array with the correct dtype before:

```
p2 = empty_like(playfield, dtype=int)
for k, v in codes.items():
    p2[playfield==k] = v
playfield = p2
```

Comment: Is there a reason to create an entire new array as opposed to just casting the type afterward?

Comment: [`playfield = playfield.astype(int) - 3`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) will also create a copy of the array with the new type, so it is a new array as well. With my approach I can avoid doing the subtraction in the end to get back the negative values, because it has the correct dtype from the beginning. I do not need any "magic" numbers.